# Calling library() in R with a variable as the argument

Tags: r

I'd like to achieve something to the effect of

```
libs = c("AER", "gbm", "caret", "MASS", "nnet", "randomForest")
for (i in libs) {
  if(!is.element(i, .packages()) {
    install.packages(i)
  }
  library(i)
}
```

The call to library(i) does not replace i with the value being stored in the variable i.  Instead, it tries to load the library called "i"

Is there a way to force i to be treated as a variable and resolved before the call to the library?

Comment: joran's answear is correct. A small improvement though would be to use ".packages(all.available = TRUE)". This way you wont be looking in the loaded libs only.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

How about `library(...,character.only = TRUE)`?

Comment: What does this `character.only = TRUE` mean? I can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: @joran. it does not work, when you have multiple package names stored as vectors.  could be because it's an old way of loading multiple packages as a character vector?

Comment: This works. `base::sapply(libs,function(x){  library(x,character.only = ,logical.return = T)})`

Comment: Wow this was such an _obvious_ solution .. (btw it does work)

Answer (score 5):

Here is the full code (combining joran's answer and adding "all.available = TRUE" ).

```
libs = c("AER", "gbm", "caret", "MASS", "nnet", "randomForest")
for (i in libs){
  if( !is.element(i, .packages(all.available = TRUE)) ) {
    install.packages(i)
  }
  library(i,character.only = TRUE)
}
```