# R Version 3.2.1 devtools Package Installation

Tags: r, devtools

I am new to R and have tried to follow a tutorial to install the `devtools` package. It seems to install the package (as can be seen below), but when I try to load it with `library(devtools)`, I receive the following error:

```
"Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘rversions’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools’"
```

I have tried to remove in re-install, but this error keeps occurring.

```
> install.packages("devtools", dependencies=TRUE)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependencies ‘RCurl’, ‘whisker’, ‘rstudioapi’, ‘roxygen2’, ‘rversions’, ‘testthat’, ‘BiocInstaller’, ‘Rcpp’, ‘rmarkdown’, ‘lintr (>= 0.2.1)’ are not available
also installing the dependency ‘git2r’

trying URL 

'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/git2r_0.10.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1554276 bytes (1.5 MB)
downloaded 1.5 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/devtools_1.8.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 339098 bytes (331 KB)
downloaded 331 KB

package ‘git2r’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘devtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Ilan\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOuW87N\downloaded_packages
> library(devtools)
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘rversions’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘devtools’
```

Comment: Have you installed [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)? It is required for the `devtools` package on Windows.

Comment: You will need to install all the dependencies and the dependencies of the dependencies to make `devtools` accessible. It seems that you are missing `rversions`. My best suggestion is to install all the dependencies `RCurl`, `whisker`, `rstudioapi`, `roxygen2`, `rversions`, `testthat`, `BiocInstaller`, `Rcpp`, `rmarkdown`, `lintr (>= 0.2.1)` and `git2r`.  You might find this link useful: `http://stackoverflow.com/a/31304113/2213164`  (fast installation and load of multiple libraries).