# Install packages via variable

Tags: r

So I tried creating a quick function to make installing and using packages easier:

```
conditional_install <- function(package_name){
  print(package_name)
  if(package_name %in% rownames(installed.packages()) == FALSE){
    install.packages(package_name)
  }
  require(package_name)
}
```

I then tried calling this function (`conditional_install("ROI")`) and I got the error:

```
Loading required package: package_name
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘package_name’
```

It seems like its trying to find a package called `package_name` instead of the value contained by `package_name`. Is there anyway to make `install.packages()` and `require()` actually use the value passed into the function instead of the variable name? The code works if I don't make it a function. Also when I print the value of the variable, it correctly prints `"ROI"`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627740/calling-library-in-r-with-a-variable-as-the-argument

Comment: note that the problem is with `require`, not `install.packages`